# NestedScrollView unwantedly scrolls to the bottom of list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a view structure like this:

```
NestedScrollView
    RecyclerView
```

I've implement pagination. Problem is, that `RecyclerView` does not work as it should, because of `NestedScrollView` (all items of recyclerview are binded at once). I solved this with:

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged() {
    int loaderItemPosition = mRecyclerView.getChildCount() - 1;
    View view = mNestedScrollView.getChildAt(mNestedScrollView.getChildCount() - 1);
    int diff = (view.getBottom() - (mNestedScrollView.getHeight() + mNestedScrollView.getScrollY()));

    if (diff == 0) {
        mNestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);
        load();
    }
}
```

Problem is, if user "flicks" (scrolls fast from top to bottom) the scroll pops to bottom list (it can be scrolled to it, would be more correct way of saying). I tried to stop that with `mNestedScrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);`. The idea was to stop scrolling when `load();` is hit. If I scroll slowly, everything works good, but even now, the scroll seems little bit laggy.

Is there a way to stop scrolling when `load();` is hit and not allow to scroll past that position (when user flicks)?

Comment: why are you using a recyclerview inside a nestedscrollview?

Comment: @A.A Well, there's no other way of achieving Collapsing toolbar and also, it's required but my intended design.

Comment: try disabling the nested scrolling of recyclerview

Comment: @ZeeshanShabbir It's already done.

Comment: For collapsing toolbar there is a component called literally `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.. there is probably a better way to achieve your goal without using such view hierarchy

Comment: check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49633143/886001)..may be you're looking for the same behavior

Comment: @A.A Yes, I'm using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` as my parent. I was more looking for this case work-around. It should not be too hard to programmatically stop scrolling (freeze it once).

Comment: stop scrolling isn't the hard part.. my point is that may be if you review your design you'll avoid the problem all together (and eventually some other problems along the way)

Comment: @A.A I see your point and that might be a good start, but for now, I'm more interested in finding a way on how to freeze a recyclerview at specific position (item). It sounds simple, but I haven't found an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in your recyclerview. hope this help